# Configure SignalR with AppCmd.exe on Azure web app

Tags: signalr, azure-web-app-service

Can you give more details of how you ran  AppCmd in Azure web app with SignalR as it requires admin rights? I don't think below will work for this reason.

```
protected void Application_Start()
        try
        {
            var windowsDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
            var command = System.IO.Path.Combine(windowsDir, @"System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config / section:system.webserver / serverRuntime / appConcurrentRequestLimit:10000");
            Process.Start(command);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure web app runs in [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). We have no permission to write system drive.

> System drive access
>
> Applications can read the system drive as controlled by ACLs on the drive. Applications **cannot write to any location on the system drive**, as implemented in the sandbox (i.e. even if ACLs allowed writing to a location on system drive, the sandbox would restrict it).

However if you choose Azure cloud service, we can use [appcmd.exe in startup task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common#configure-iis-startup-with-appcmdexe). Of course, it will work like a charm if choose Azure VM as web server.